# How to reduce the test execution time in Appium

Tags: appium

For Android automation tests I want to reduce the time of Execution between test cases.

Apart from using ID's is there any way around?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using xpaths for selectors you should avoid them. Xpath is the one of the slowest selector method. If you are using id's beside of xpath and other selectors, this is the most efficient way to use selector. (you already mentioned it, you are using id's so you don't need to worry about the selectors)

Second thing to improve is waits. If you are using implicit waits and/or `thread.sleep()` you should get rid of them and should try to implement conditional explicit wait like `waitUntilElementVisible`. This gonna reduce your unnecessary wait time. And if you are also using verification methods for validating the elements which should be disappear at the page, you should keep waiting time minimum.

Third, you can use "noReset" capability as `true` in to your `Desired Capabilities`. This capability will check your emulator or device for reset needing. If there is no reason to reset, the initialization will take less.

Fourth, Turning off the animations will also reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Android platform only it would make sense to reconsider the tool selection and switch to [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) which is faster than Appium due to its implementation nature. Check out [How to Get Started with Espresso (Android)](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/getting_started_espresso/) article for more information

If you have to proceed with Appium:

1. Consider using the most optimal [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) (if possible use ID instead of XPath)
2. Consider using [Page Object Design Pattern](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Page-objects.md), it will allow you to get rid of necessary and unnecessary waits and stale elements errors due to [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) routine
3. Consider [running your Appium tests in parallel](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments :) I'll practice the same.